# Query between two time frames for multiple days in Tsql

Tags: t-sql, time

I am trying to determine how much meds were given between the hours of 22:00 on one day and 06:00 the next day.  How would I add this in my where clause to get a count given between this time frame?  I am not sure even where to begin on this.

Answer (score 0):

Please post an example of yout table.
If each line in your table is one med that is given:

```
select COUNT(*) as Number_of_Meds
from t
where datetime_column_name >= CAST('2019-12-24 22:00' as datetime) 
    and datetime_column_name < CAST('2019-12-25 06:00' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding my answer.

where ((DATEPART(hh,d.ActionDateTime)>22 and DATEPART(hh,d.ActionDateTime) < 00) or (DATEPART(hh,d.ActionDateTime)>00 and DATEPART(hh,d.ActionDateTime) < 6))